# Print a foreach blocks and show them with a more button

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I need help ..

I have a list of items that prints with a foreach loop.. 
I need to print  25 items at a time when I click on the button "show other", for this I  used a LimitIterator.

I also need do it without reload the page, for this i used AJAX. 
My problem is that I need to calculate how many items have already been printed, so that the button shows other  get this information and every time you use this button, it print the next 25 items(under the previous 25 items) with the foreach loop that I included in a function.

How can I do? Thanks in advance.

**getForeach.php**

```
public static function spawn_list($list_start = 0, $list_limit = 25, $n = 0) {
......
    $items = new ArrayIterator($items);
    echo '<ul class="my_list">';
    foreach (new LimitIterator($items, $list_start, $list_limit) as $item){
        $n++;
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span class="views">'.$item->viewers.'Viewers</span>';
        echo '<span class="name">'.$item->name->display_name.'</span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
 }

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'more_items' : spawn_list();break;
    }
}
```

**AJAX script**

```
$('#more_button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : '/getForeach.php',
            data:{action: 'more_items'},
            async : true,
            cache : false,
            success : function(output) {
                $("#test").html(output);
            },
            error : function (output) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

**Mypage**

```
 <div id="test"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="more_button">SHOW OTHER</a>
```

**EIDT:** I need do this for performance reasons..so any advice is welcome.

Comment: Just pass the start value to use with your AJAX call – and increment it in your JavaScript every time you have loaded a new row of items …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the number of items that have been returned in a hidden input field

```
<input type='hidden' name='item_count' value='' />
```

grab this value in your ajax call and pass it to the script which you can get create some logic to return what you need, if it's a database query consider using `LIMIT`

You will also want change your success function to use `.append()` Using `.html()` will just replace the HTML that is already set.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I put this hidden input? If I insert it in the foreach function to get the value of the variable $ n this will not work. As will print many different hidden input and ajax will refer only to the first of them.

Comment: Place the hidden field in your HTML and not in the php foreach. You can then reference the input field at your ajax call using `$('input[name=item_count]').val();` You can set and retrieve the value this way. If you're still unsure i can write out a small example.